# How to start nautilus-dropbox with Gnome and kfilebox with KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, dropbox

I use Ubuntu/Kubuntu 12.10 with KDE 4.10 and Unity, switching beetween the two depending on what I intend to do.

My question is:

How can I make sure that

- the package nautilus-dropbox is only started when I login into Unity
- and when logging in into KDE only kfilebox is started?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are your friends.

Basically add those apps to your sessions (collections of app that each desktop env, will start after you login).